# why am getting this npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am new in React and I'm trying to create a React app using the VS Code terminal

This the command that I am trying to run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

This is the error I am getting:

> ```
> npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
> npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
> npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-jest failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:443
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> ...
> ...
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-16T07_54_37_069Z-debug.log
> ```

Please what should I do?

Comment: Did you check your internet connection? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: yes have check my internet connection

Comment: npm cache clean --force

@Emmanuel try this

Comment: have tryed it, still showing thw same errors

Comment: I successfully mimicked this error. The network connection was ok, but Google Drive was uploading a 7GB file, consuming all of the bandwidth. I tried several times to install 3 packages at once, but it always got me to the same error you are getting. After I paused the Google Drive sync - packages were installed without a problem!! I suggest you double-check your internet connection as it might be overloaded, try connecting to a different network, and restart the machine - a process could be overloading your connection.